# indicator-datetime stops the disk from spinning down

Tags: 13.10, indicator, battery, upstart

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 on a laptop, and have `laptop-mode-tools` installed.

I've noticed that, while running on battery, the laptop's hard disk is not spinning down successfully.
About every five seconds, the disk starts spinning down but then something makes it spin back up again.

I've investigated this a bit (with the help of Google), and found some things:

- I've installed and run `iotop`. Every time the disk starts spinning down, iotop reports that the process `init --user` is writing to the disk and using 99% IO.
- After letting the laptop "alone" for 2 or 3 minutes on battery, `find -cmin -1` on my home directory reports that the file `~/.cache/upstart/unity-panel-service.log` was recently modified.
- If I run `tail -f ~/.cache/upstart/unity-panel-service.log`, I noticed that this file is updated every second, and the line

  ```
  ** (unity-panel-service:2711): WARNING **: Unable to support GtkImageType: 0
  ```

  is appended.
- `sudo strace -p <"init --user"'s PID>` constantly outputs the following lines (or similar):

  ```
  read(3, 0x7fff3c96871b, 1)              = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
  waitid(P_ALL, 0, {}, WNOHANG|WEXITED|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = 0
  select(37, [3 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 19 20 21 26 27 29 36], [], [7 8 9 10 12 20 21], NULL) = 1 (in [36])
  read(36, "\r\n** (unity-panel-service:2711):"..., 8192) = 160
  read(36, 0x7f5a06c21830, 8032)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
  fstat(14, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=384106, ...}) = 0
  write(14, "\r\n** (unity-panel-service:2711):"..., 160) = 160
  ```
- As a side note, `cat /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs` returns `500` while on AC power and `60000`  while on battery.

Has anyone noticed the same thing?
I don't know if this occurs in a fresh install (or if this occurred in 13.04).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've investigated even further before posting this, and the culprit seems to be the date/time indicator.
I had configured the indicator to display the seconds.
If I remove that setting, the *unity-panel-service.log* file no longer is updated every second (but, maybe, every minute), and the disk spins down successfully.

So, the workaround seems to be: don't display the seconds in the date/time indicator, or remove it.

I think I'll report this bug.
I'll leave this here in case this could be useful to someone.

Comment: Reported: https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-datetime/+bug/1251222

Answer (score 0):

I updated from 13.04 to 13.10 and have the same thing. Not every 1 but every 5 sec.
Closing the indicator-datetime solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For another reference to the bug which caused unity-service-panel.log go crazy generating over 18GB worth of space :-o
[unity-service-panel.log taking 18+ GB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/387393/unity-service-panel-log-taking-18-gb?answertab=votes#tab-top)