# unity-service-panel.log taking 18+ GB

Tags: unity, 13.10, ssd, panel

Im having strange unity-service-panel.log file behavior in Ubuntu 13.10., which in 5-6 days filled up to 18.5 GB worth of space. Its located in /home/user/.cache/upstart . I have no idea whats going on? If it continues I wont have no spare area for other services etc. for normal operating OS, Im down to 500+MB. Ubuntu is running on 26GB all / root SSD partition. Do you have any suggestions/solutions for my problem. Thx in advance!

Comment: And what is written to the log?

Comment: I dont know, I couldnt open it. For the time being I deleted the file, but have a feeling its gone fill up fast.

Comment: Try opening the file again soon so it is still very small, and add (some of) the output to your question.

Comment: This is how it looks right now: http://pastebin.com/FGQa1H61

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This look like a bug. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/376890/221281) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-datetime/+bug/1251222). (Please click in the bugreport that the bug affects you.) The first link has a half-workaround: disable the seconds display in the time indicator applet. This will stop putting out that error message in every second, but it will still output it every minute.

Based on the error message it looks like the applet can't load an image file either because it is missing or it is in wrong format. So please disable any modifications you tried made to the panel. (The error complains about a missing user avatar, so please remove your avatar.)

Comment: Thx for your effort, it seems it is a bug. Iv disabled time and date in panel altogether, so will see if .log file will stay under controla or will it go wilde.