# How to disable upstart logging?

Tags: 14.04, upstart

I am suffering from this bug:
[unity-service-panel.log taking 18+ GB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/387393/unity-service-panel-log-taking-18-gb?newreg=3a4c2d0629d74b068a3dd513aa6b2778)

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.

I can't find anything in the internet about how to fix this, other than disabling unity-service-panel, which I don't want to do. Nor do I want to do something drastic like re-install Ubuntu.

Is there is an easy way to disable the upstart logs?

Comment: read the log and see if you can fix the error message.

Comment: If it is a bug, file a bug report but if there is no solution for 13.10 posted here the only option is bug report.